# No wrapping using Bootstrap 4 flex

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to have two columns with several block that wrap into the second column when I use `flex-base: 100%`. Here is an example of what I want:

```css
.container1 {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

.item1 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 70%;
}

.item2 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 28%;
}

.item3 {
  width: 2%;
}

.break-column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.item4 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="border border-danger d-flex flex-column flex-wrap container1 p-0 m-0" >

  <div class="item1 order-1 border border-primary rounded">
  Flex item 1
  </div>
  
  <div class="item2 order-4 border border-secondary rounded">
  Flex item 2
  </div>
 
  
  <div class="item3 order-3 border border-info
  rounded flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1 pr-0 mr-0 break-column">
  Flex item 3
  </div>
  
    <div class="item4 order-2 border border-info
  rounded flex-shrink-1 pr-0 mr-0">
  Flex item 4
  </div>


</div>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

So red is the "container" and Flex item 3 is the div element with `flex-base: 100%` which forces the wrap. It works nicely as Flex item 2 indeed wrapped to the next column. Also notice I used order on the elements to have not Flex item 4 wrap but Flex item 2.

However in my project I use Bootstrap 4 and somehow it does not work. There is no wrapping at all. I think it is because of using "container" at the root of my project which is a Bootstrap container with its own characteristics. When simulate it in a fiddle it indeed does not work anymore:

```css
.item1 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 70%;
}

.item2 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 28%;
}

.item3 {
  width: 2%;
}

.break-column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.item4 {
  height: 10%;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="container">

<div class="border border-danger d-flex flex-column flex-wrap  p-0 m-0" >

  <div class="item1 order-1 border border-primary rounded">
  Flex item 1
  </div>
  
  <div class="item2 order-4 border border-secondary rounded">
  Flex item 2
  </div>
 
  
  <div class="item3 order-3 border border-info
  rounded flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1 pr-0 mr-0 break-column">
  Flex item 3
  </div>
  
    <div class="item4 order-2 border border-info
  rounded flex-shrink-1 pr-0 mr-0">
  Flex item 4
  </div>


</div> 

</div>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see just one column, so no wrapping. Why is that? And how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The container needs a height. So setting

```
.container1 {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}
```

solves it. The bootstrap container has no height apparently.